# What does the double colon sign (::) mean in phonology?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics

What does the `::` sign mean in phonology or historical linguistics?

Here's an example I saw:

> yeri :: yatu

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_colon

Comment: That’s not really linguistics; it’s logic, taken over by linguistics. (It’s the first of the two options on the Wikipedia, analogy symbolism. Not the scope resolution operator.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd read that double colon sign as "compares to" or (given appropriate context) "is cognate to" or "is analogous to".

Comment: Thank you very much! And what is two arrow signs above a check mark?

Comment: I don't know the sign you describe, I can't visualize any sign known to me from the description.

Comment: I see. Thank you!